# Testing nested controllers: NoMethodError: undefined method `empty?' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, factory-bot, rspec-rails, slug

I have been trying to get my controller test pass... 
My routes.rb

```
namespace :school do
  resource :account, :except => [:new, :create, :destroy], :controller => 'account'
  resources :classes, :path => "" do
   resources :discussions do
    resources :comments
  end
  resources :materials
end
end
```

MY DiscussionController specs:

```
describe "POST 'create'" do
 before(:each) do
  @user = FactoryGirl.create(:coordinator_user)
  login_user(@user)
  @klass = FactoryGirl.build(:klass)
  @klass.creator = @user
  @klass.save
  @parameters = FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:discussion, :klass_id => @klass, :user_id => @user)
end

context "with valid parameters" do
  it "creates a new job" do
    expect { post :create, :class_id => @klass.id, :discussion => @parameters }.to   change(Discussion, :count).by(1)
  end

  it "should create a new discussion" do
    post :create, :class_id => @klass.id
    response.should be_redirect
    response.should redirect_to(school_account_path(assigns(:discussion).id))
    assigns(:discussion).should_not be_nil
    assigns(:discussion).should_not be_new_record
  end

end
```

I get errors: 1) NoMethodError: undefined method `empty?' for nil:NilClass  # ./lib/slug.rb:3:in`slug'
Cannot understand what is nil here.

Comment: HOW do I debug?? I tried to print PP @klass.id.. it does print klass id. ANy suggestion on learning testing in ROR? resources to learn??

Comment: how does your model look like? are you using the friendly_id gem, or is the slug.rb your own helper class? can you please post the relevant code too.

Comment: Here is the slug code:   def slug
    if not respond_to? :name or name.empty?
      id
    else
      "#{id}-#{name}".to_url
    end
  end

  def to_param
    slug
  end

Comment: it seems, that name is nil..that´s why you get the nil:NilClass error. Where does "name" come from? You could put this method into your model, than the instance and the instance.name is available..

Comment: I checked pp discussion.name it is not nil... no idea what is nil here??